# Difference between stringBuillder append(CONST) and append("new string")

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Can I get some concrete explanation of memory and runtime overhead with the below two statements?

1. String CONST = "string constant";
   StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
   sb1.append(CONST);
2. StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
   sb2.append("string constant");

Does second create string object and add in stringpool?
Is there any scenario(consider many string appends as well) where we can justify one is better than other?

Comment: They are identical.

Comment: write code that is easier to read and understand; and any string literal is interned; these are identical here

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in memory or runtime overhead between these two versions.

Use whichever seems more readable or maintainable.  If you're reusing the same string constant in many places, the constant is long, or might change, then pulling out a constant might be appropriate.

Comment: One question before append a string object will be created for "string constant"?
And if we have multiple append with hard coded string each and every time new String object will be created before append?

Comment: No.  There is no difference.  It will be turned into a constant in both cases.  Like I said: there is *no difference.* Not even an unimportant difference, zero difference.

Answer (score 1):

In reference to the runtime overhead, running a simulation of both methods yielded almost identical results.

My tests were done with 10,000,000,000 iterations and the runtime was:

- **Method 1** - 95109ms (~9.5ns average)
- **Method 2** - 95002ms (~9.5ns average)

So definitely no noticeable difference in performance.

---

Therefore, as @LouisWasserman said in their answer, just use the one that keeps your code clean and legible.